# How do I escape the dash '-' in Presto when accessing elements from an unnested array?

Tags: sql, arrays, presto

Using Presto, I want to access `students.home-room` which is an array struct within a `classrooms` table.

I tried:

```
SELECT
class.students.home-room
FROM
school_table_json
cross join unnest (classrooms) c (class)
WHERE year = '2022'
```

I get an error:
**Column 'class.students.home' cannot be resolved**

The error suggests Presto interprets 'home-room' as 'home' and can't find the truncated 'home' in hive (as it doesn't exist). Similar structs can be accessed, like class.students.grades. Presto errors handling the dash '-'...?

**How do I escape the dash '-' in Presto when accessing elements in an unnested array?**

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset (id, r) as (
    values (1, CAST(ROW(1, 2.0) AS ROW(x BIGINT, "home-room" DOUBLE)))
)

-- query
select r."home-room"
from dataset;
```

Output:

| home-room |
| --- |
| 2.0 |